# Problemas al mostrar resultado con EntitiesFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, mvc

tengo la siguiente duda, porque cuando utilizo lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TPConvenios.App_Data
{
    public partial class Usuario
    {

public bool tienePermisoConvenio(Permiso permiso, Convenio cnv)
        {
            using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
            {
                var permic = db.Permiso_Usuario_Convenio.FirstOrDefault(puc => puc.Convenio.idConvenio == cnv.idConvenio && puc.idPermiso == permiso.idPermiso);
                if (null != permic)
                {
                    return permic.estaActivo;
                }
                else
                {
                    return permic.estaActivo = false;
                }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Me muestra el siguiente resultado, el cual es errado debido a que en mi BD no están encendido todos es decir varios estan en 0 `false` y otros en `true` 1
[image]

Pero utilizando el siguiente código

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TPConvenios.App_Data
{
    public partial class Usuario
    {

public bool tienePermisoConvenio(Permiso permiso, Convenio cnv)
        {
            var permic = Permiso_Usuario_Convenio.FirstOrDefault(puc => puc.Convenio.idConvenio == cnv.idConvenio && puc.idPermiso == permiso.idPermiso);
                if (null != permic)
                {
                    return permic.estaActivo;
                }
                else
                {
                    return permic.estaActivo = false;
                }
           }
   }
}
```

me muestra lo siguiente lo cual es lo correcto, pues así lo tengo en mi BD.

[image]

PORQUE ME MUESTRA LOS DATOS ERRONEOS CUANDO UTILIZO

```
var permic = db.Permiso_Usuario_Convenio.FirstOrDefault(puc => puc.Convenio.idConvenio == cnv.idConvenio && puc.idPermiso == permiso.idPermiso);
```

PERO  ME TRAE LOS DATOS CORRECTO AL UTILIZAR

```
   var permic = Permiso_Usuario_Convenio.FirstOrDefault(puc => puc.Convenio.idConvenio == cnv.idConvenio && puc.idPermiso == permiso.idPermiso);
```

Cuando verifico la variable `permic` en ambos me trae lo mismo, aun así no logro entender porque al utilizar la `db` de mi instancia `EF` me arroja todo los datos encendidos y al quitárselo me los trae bien.

ah decir verdad me gustaría utilizar mi instancia de `EF`

ANEXO CODIGO DE LA VISTA

```
@using TPConvenios.App_Data;
@model Usuario
@{
    Layout = null;
    int idRowTable = 0;
    //ViewBag.usuariosConvenio = ViewBag.usuariosConvenio ?? new List<Usuario>();
    Convenio cnv = ViewBag.convenio;
    List<TPConvenios.App_Data.Permiso> permisos = ViewBag.permisos;
    var convenioseleccionado = (null != cnv);
}

<div id="view_Usuarios" style="display: block">
        @if (Model.creaUsuarios)
    {
        List<Usuario> usuariosConvenio = (List<Usuario>)ViewBag.usuariosConvenio;
        <div>
            <table id="tblAdminUsuarios">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td-orderable">
                            Nombre Usuario
                        </th>
                            foreach (var permiso in permisos)
                            {
                            <th class="td-center">
                                @permiso.Descripcion
                            </th>
                            }
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var usuario in usuariosConvenio)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @usuario.userName @if (usuario.supervisorCNV == true)
                            {
                                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/admi.png" />
                            }
                       </td>
                       foreach (var permiso in permisos)
                            {
                                var tienePermiso = usuario.tienePermisoConvenio(permiso, cnv);
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="check@(usuario.idUsuario)@(permiso.idPermiso)" data-indice="@idRowTable" type="checkbox" class="switcheryChk" 
                                        onchange="CambiarPermiso(@usuario.idUsuario, @cnv.idConvenio,@permiso.idPermiso, this)"  @(tienePermiso ? "checked" : string.Empty)  />
                                    </td>
                            }
                    </tr>
                        idRowTable++;
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Es bastante sencillo, db lo declaras como new, al ser una nueva instancia no tiene valores

Comment: @NicolasOñate Existe alguna manera de cambiar eso? es decir utilizar la instancia para que me traiga los valores.

Comment: si, en el constructor `new  TuClase(//cosas que quieras)` y en tu clase declarar el constructor con eso que desees pasar

Comment: porque no usas un dbContext y lo inyectas en el constructor? de ese modo no tendrías este tipo de problemas

Comment: @CarlosMarceloBuffaOrtíz puedes darme un poco mas de detalle por favor

Comment: @NicolasOñate lo intente así, pero no tengo el resultado que quiero

Comment: @TheRiddler estas usando ASP.Net clásico cierto? no ASP.Net core?

Comment: @CarlosMarceloBuffaOrtíz, correcto estoy usando ASP.NET clasico, MVC4

Comment: mira este link donde explica como hacerlo con asp. net mvc  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection